# PyTorch: Для бинарной функции активации работает ли градиентный спуск?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

Возникла мысль, что для одной схемы сетки в одном специальном слое будет удобна бинарная функция активации. И возникает вопрос, будет ли такое работать для градиентного спуска, т.к. у бинарной функции производная почти везде равна нулю?

Например вот такое:

```py
class MySpecLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(10, 5)
    def forward(self, x):
        return (self.linear(x) > 0).float()
```

Т.е. возвращается ноль или один, и это значение дальшей пойдет в другой слой.

Comment: представим числа больше 4 и до 7 в бинарной форме, у них 3 бит постоянно включён. то есть для 4=х чисел этот бит включён, но это не значит, что производная для этого числа не вычисляема. так же и для битового представления. смело пользуйтесь. для глубокого знакомства повторить курс дискретной математики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нейросеть неглубокая, то можно использовать, если же глубокая, то может происходить затухание градиента, при обратном распространении ошибки, так как у вас, судя по коду сеть состоит из 1 слоя, то по идее бинарная функция активации не должна создавать проблем.